# Why does UILabel TapGesture only work after label initialization?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following code to initialize a label:

```swift
let forgotPasswordLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Forgot password?"
        label.font = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.typographyScheme.subtitle1
        label.textColor = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryColor
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.accessibilityRespondsToUserInteraction = true
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
```

And later on I add it to the subview as such:

```swift
let passwordLabel = forgotPasswordLabel
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onForgotPasswordClick))
passwordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
self.view.addSubview(passwordLabel)
```

If I do the code as such then it works fine, however if I put the tapGesture code inside the label forgotPasswordLabel initialization, the tap gesture does not fire. Why is that?

Code that does not work:

```swift
let forgotPasswordLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Forgot password?"
        label.font = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.typographyScheme.subtitle1
        label.textColor = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryColor
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onForgotPasswordClick))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
```

Does this have something to do with the garbage collector? Unrecognized bounds for the UILabel? Or something else?

Comment: Can you tell where do you use forgotPasswordLabel in the case when it does not work?

Comment: I add to the subview in the viewDidLoad method as the simple line self.view.addSubview(forgotPasswordLabel)

Comment: see the following explanation should help you to understand the reason behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tapGesture` in following code is added inside the `Closure` initializer, and with that you assign target as `self` which is not valid. Coz `self` here is not the `ViewController`

```
let forgotPasswordLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Forgot password?"
        label.font = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.typographyScheme.subtitle1
        label.textColor = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryColor
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onForgotPasswordClick))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
```

Where as in the following code where the `tapGesture` is working as expected you are setting target as `self` which is the `ViewController` and that is valid.

```
let forgotPasswordLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Forgot password?"
    label.font = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.typographyScheme.subtitle1
    label.textColor = ApplicationScheme.instance.containerScheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryColor
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.accessibilityRespondsToUserInteraction = true
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let passwordLabel = forgotPasswordLabel
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onForgotPasswordClick))
passwordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
self.view.addSubview(passwordLabel)
```

In case of `tapGesture` when you set the target it tells that where to look for the `action` when the gesture happens

Comment: Is there a method of doing the gesture initialization inside the closure instead of outside of it?

Comment: interesting question, let me check quickly

Comment: I would say that the approach will create more issue but will let you know here if i find a best way to do it